# Pop up window to display some stuff in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-popupwindow

I am trying to make something like a pop-up window, that would appear when clicked on a view in a fragment. I want this pop-up window or whatever, to not make the fragment dark, like a Dialog Fragment does.
And I also want the pop up to be positioned where the view is clicked.
Would be good if it has its own activity and layout so I can do some custom changes in it.
Can you plese show me some sample code?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The following should work perfect in accordance with your specification. Call this method from inside `onClick(View v)` of `OnClickListener` assigned to the View:

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

    View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Example: If you have a TextView inside `popup_layout.xml`    
    TextView tv = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    tv.setText(....);

    // Initialize more widgets from `popup_layout.xml`
    ....
    ....

    // If the PopupWindow should be focusable
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    // If you need the PopupWindow to dismiss when when touched outside 
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

    int location[] = new int[2];

    // Get the View's(the one that was clicked in the Fragment) location
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    // Using location, the PopupWindow will be displayed right under anchorView
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                                     location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());

}
```

The comments should explain this well enough. `anchorView` is the `v` from `onClick(View v)`.

Comment: awesome, works so far, but how do I make it have a border or something?

Comment: @БориславМинчев Well, place the whole `popup` layout inside a `FrameLayout` with black background. Set `popup` layout's background to white and give it a margin of `2dp`.

Comment: too complicated :D I did it with a background picture with a frame, and the inside color transparent like 70%. anyway, the above answers was what I wanted thank you

Comment: Inside a fragment I had to use `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`.