# how to make background of dialog back

Tags: android

I would like to solve the problem I've got. I made a dialog above a activity of android, but I would like to make the background black(opaque). All the guide shows only how to make it transparent. How can I make it opaque?

Comment: This Link May help you Pleas check it once


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461990/pop-up-window-to-display-some-stuff-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can control it.

After creating dialog:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**Upd**: you can even add blur behind the dialog:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Comment: just a reminder; blur for background is deprecated after for API Level 14+ .

Answer (score 0):

Hello If i understand your question correctly then you can do it by below code :

```
Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);
        d.setAlpha(130);
        mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line :

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(0xff000000));
```

hope it helps :)