# add fragment to popup window in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

My problem is that i want to add fragment to my pop up window to display some information when a list is clicked. My list contains custom adapter. below is what i want to do :-

When list item is clicked, i get that model from adapterview and pass it to JobSearchModel. Now JobSearchModel contains the information that i want to display on JobDescription fragement. But i don't know how to add fragement to pop up window.

```
searchResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                JobSearchModel jobs = (JobSearchModel) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                JobDescription jobDescription = new JobDescription();

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("jobs", jobs);

                jobDescription.setArguments(args);

                popupWindow.showAtLocation(jobDescription, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey even I am having this problem. Did you by any chance found a solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

[Copied From HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462324/3322203)

The following should work perfect in accordance with your specification. Call this method from inside `onClick(View v)` of `OnClickListener` assigned to the View:

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

    View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Example: If you have a TextView inside `popup_layout.xml`    
    TextView tv = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    tv.setText(....);

    // Initialize more widgets from `popup_layout.xml`
    ....
    ....

    // If the PopupWindow should be focusable
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

    // If you need the PopupWindow to dismiss when when touched outside 
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

    int location[] = new int[2];

    // Get the View's(the one that was clicked in the Fragment) location
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    // Using location, the PopupWindow will be displayed right under anchorView
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                                     location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());

}
```

The comments should explain this well enough. `anchorView` is the `v` from `onClick(View v)`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about adding a Fragment to a popup window.

Comment: From the help page : "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."