# Android custom keyboard popup keyboard on long press

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events, android-input-method

I have custom Android keyboard:

```
    public class CustomKeyboard extends Keyboard{...}  

    public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView{...}

    public class CustomKeyboardIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{...}
```

On some keys, I have `popupKeyboard` and `popupCharacters`:

```
<Key android:codes="144" android:keyLabel="0" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/key_popup" android:popupCharacters=")" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
```

xml/key_popup.xml:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:keyWidth="10%p"
      android:horizontalGap="0px"
      android:verticalGap="0px"
      android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height" >
</Keyboard>
```

But when I longPress on "0" key popup with ")" shows, but it stays there until I press "X" button or ")" character. It looks like this:
[image: My keyboard]

And I want it to be opened only while I am holding a finger on. Something like on Samsung or HTC keyboard:
[image: Samsung keyboard]

Can someone help me please?

**EDIT** Is it at least possible to change the appearance of this popup? I want it to have same background and keys as whole keyboard I have made/

Comment: anybody got solution for this question ?

Comment: I think you have to make custom views for everything if you want to customize the keyboard... But I don't know how.

Comment: This link help full you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key

Comment: I'm wanting to do something similar. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I'm going to use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18462324

Comment: did you find any solution please update

Comment: @MateenChaudhry Did you found any solution please?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `PopupWindow` class and populate it with custom layout.

```
View custom = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, new FrameLayout(context));
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
popup.setContentView(custom);
```

and on long press

```
//Get x,y based on the touch position
//Get width, height based on your layout
if(popup.isShowing()){
    popup.update(x, y, width, height);
} else {
    popup.setWidth(width);
    popup.setHeight(height);
    popup.showAtLocation(yourKeyboardView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);
}
```

On click in the popup you can dismiss it

```
popup.dismiss();
```