# Android softkeyboard popup view on key long press

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow

I am developing Android soft keyboard:

```
public class CustomKeyboard extends Keyboard{...}  

    public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView{...}

    public class CustomKeyboardIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{...}
```

On some keys, I have popupKeyboard and popupCharacters:

```
<Key android:codes="144" android:keyLabel="0" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/key_popup" android:popupCharacters=")" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
```

xml/key_popup.xml:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:keyWidth="10%p"
  android:horizontalGap="0px"
  android:verticalGap="0px"
  android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height" >
```

But when I longPress on "0" key popup with ")" shows, but it stays there until I press "X" button or ")" character.

And I want it to be opened only while I am holding a finger on. Something like on iPhone keyboard:

[image: i want popup like image]

Anyone can help?

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for modification my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to create your own popup in this case, using PopupWindow or Dialog.

then you go into your keyboard and overwrite your onRelease method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {  
    myPopupWindow.dismiss();
}
```

To make your own popupWindow for keyboard see this thread:
[Android custom keyboard popup keyboard on long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390175/android-custom-keyboard-popup-keyboard-on-long-press)